# Simple target="_blank"

Tags: php, html

I'm having a really hard time simply trying to include a target="_blank" in this PHP condition. Could someone please help me out?

```
if (!empty($options['help_uid'])) echo '<li class="help-icon">
   <a href="' . $options['help_uid'] . '">'
. '<img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
. '/icons/help-icon.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Help">'
. '</a></li>';
```

Comment: you mean like this ? <a target="_blank" href ...?

Comment: What if you simply include in it ? Is it not working ?

Comment: Was overlooking this thing, thanks for pointing me out guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use like this

```
if (!empty($options['help_uid'])) echo '<li class="help-icon">
   <a href="' . $options['help_uid'] . '" target="_blank">'
. '<img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
. '/icons/help-icon.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Help">'
. '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Thanks Vipan, exactly what I needed! Feel bad I was overcomplicating it... Long day, I need some rest =) Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
if (!empty($options['help_uid'])) { ?>
<li class="help-icon">
   <a href="<?php echo  $options['help_uid']; ?>" target="_blank">
<img src=" <?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/icons/help-icon.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Help"/>
</a>
</li>
```